# how to block ip from head or ping or get or post to webserver (using apache and windows)?

Tags: apache, denial-of-service

am using apache 2.4.9 latest with windows 7 i am using some modules like

```
limitipconn_module 
security2_module
```

but using wireshark i get unlimited request to busy my webserver (DOS) from some ip address i have deny them and their ip ranges basicly on isp hostname but using proxies would be a new problem and i can not deny all ip address so other clients can not visit my website

is there any method to block only ip address after 50 request per 10 seconds ? i have seen

```
mod_evasive
```

but it is not compatible with apache 2.4.9 or any idea for using firewall ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a [policy based QoS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/wndp/qos-in-windows-7), this allows you to perform rate limiting on particular IP addresses based on a particular policy.  This way, you can allow IP addresses to visit your side, but when they perform a particular action (accessing a certain port, accessing a particular URL...), you'll only allow a limited number of sessions.

It will limit the resources your server allocates to them.  It may be a good thing to look at potential "DoS" protection from your ISP, but that depends on yours and their definition of DoS.  This could be just the "noise" of the Internet.

Also, the [ApacheHaus](https://web.archive.org/web/20210121171637/https://www.apachehaus.net/modules/) has Mod_evasive for Apache 2.4 on windows, this should allow you to put in some rate limiting as well.

Comment: ijust resloved the problem yesterday by calling firewall from mod_evasive and i just arrived to install mo_evasive 2.4 i downloaded 2.2 i have not seen 2.4 ! thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of solutions which vary in their sophistication and effort / price...
you can refer to this article for some simple techniques: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security-vpn/kerberos/13634-newsflash.html

There are of course paid of the shelf solutions including cloud based solutions so you dont have to do much on your side such as from Incapsula, Akamai and others...